# Is it possible to cancel parent hover style when a child element is hovered?

Tags: css

Both parent and child divs have hover styles defined but I'd like to get parent hover style canceled when child element is hovered (**using only css**).

Is it possible?

Comment: CSS doesn't really give you an API to "cancel" effects, but you could possibly order your selectors so you have a style defined for `.parent .child:hover` that differs from `.parent:hover .child:hover`.

Comment: research css specificity

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712198/hover-only-on-parent

Comment: Thanks Two-Bit Alchemist but what you offered only effects child element. The problematic one is parent element. It seems like it's impossible. I'll mark below one as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, as the name suggests, cascading style sheets (css) only allow to set children properties depending on the ancestors.  Selecting elements depending on their children is not possible.

In short: No.

Comment: There is actually a plan to make this possible for CSS4 using subjects: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to "cheat" for the effect you want. Just can't be nested parent and child, but they can be grouped in a containing div.

[JS Bin Sample](http://jsbin.com/hufuv/2/edit)

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
.parent{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.child {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:25px;;
  left:25px;
}

.parent:hover {
  background-color:green;
}
.child:hover {
  background-color:yellow;
}

  <div>
<div class="parent">
   </div>
  <div class="child">

  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. I liked what you did but I should solve this without touching markup or javascript if possible. Seems impossible though.

Comment: No problem...the only way to do it that I know of without changing markup is to use sass CSS http://sass-lang.com/ You can nest within the css.