# Nested hover events, only apply to most direct hovered element

Tags: javascript, css, hover

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
  outline: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
}

.inner {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}

.hover {
  outline: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.outer, .inner').on('mouseenter', function(e){

  $(this).addClass('hover');

}).on('mouseleave', function(e){

  $(this).removeClass('hover');

});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tEAiG/

Is there a way I can make it so the hover class is only applied to the directly hovered element? ie. When the mouse is inside the inner div only it is yellow, and not outer as well?

Comment: I think this is a known limitation of mouse entry/leave. Same problem exists for file drag/drop events.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673490/is-it-possible-to-cancel-parent-hover-style-when-a-child-element-is-hovered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are handling the hover by adding the class yourself, rather than using CSS `:hover`, you can [stop propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) of the event in your handler when reacting to the `mouseenter`.

That way, if the handler is reacting to the .inner it will stopPropagation() to prevent the event from also going to the .outer

Another issue is going to be that you must have entered the outer and handled it in order to even reach the inner, so you will want to remove the hover class that *must have* been added to the parent node.

Demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/3p96q/)

Comment: The issue I have with .stopPropagation() is that in the project this is from it seems to meddle with other event handlers I've got going on elsewhere.

Comment: @dangerDAN I've updated http://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/3p96q/1/ so you can come in from the right side directly into the .inner -- if you comment out the stopPropagation you'll see both divs change. If your divs will always be completely nested you should be able to do without stopping propagation, as removing hover from the parent when the inner is entered should be enough.

Comment: issue here is if you then come out of .inner, .hover isn't re-applied to .outer. That could be solved with using mousemove instead, which is actually what I'm currently doing as a work around, however if you see my other comments on here, I feel that is a bit hackish, so my question was to see if there was different way of dealing with the event.

Comment: Yeah, you may be able to use mouseleave rather than mousemove, but your "work around" is really the only way to do it.

Comment: just to add to the above.. use `.parents()` so that if the user hovers too fast, it will ensure that it removes `.hover` on all the parent elements

Answer (score 0):

A possible method could be removing the hover class from the outer div and then applying it to the inner div when the mouse is inside the inner div, since whenever you go inside the inner div, the hover class is applied on both divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the class hover on the parent div when the mouse enters the inner div
Like this:

```
$('.outer, .inner').on('mouseenter', function(e){

  $(this).addClass('hover');
  $(this).parent(".outer").removeClass('hover');

}).on('mouseleave', function(e){

  $(this).removeClass('hover');
  $(this).parent(".outer").addClass('hover');

});
```

I feel like this is a bit of a hack and can be improved by being more specific with the selectors instead of creating just one function for both .outer and .inner

Example on: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzILE/

Comment: The problem with this is that when leaving the inner div the outer won't change color, but it can be fixed by having another event when .inner is left.

Comment: This is the work-around I am currently using (I actually loop through all of the element's ancestors, removing the hover class on each - in my app `.outer` isn't a direct parent of `.inner`). I wanted to know if there was a way of doing this that is much less hackish.

Comment: Once you go inside the small div, and leave it, but are still within the outer div then it does not work...until you completely leave the outer div and come back in.

Comment: Sorry, did not see that when I typed my response :-)

Comment: @dangerDAN well if that's the case I think more explicit selectors/classes could be used. Instead of using generic .parent() filter it through a selector

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by making a separate handler for each one.

```
$('.outer').on('mouseenter', function(e){      
  $(this).addClass('hover');      
}).on('mouseleave', function(e){     
  $(this).removeClass('hover');      
});

$('.inner').on('mouseenter', function(e){
  $(this).addClass('hover');
  $('.outer').removeClass('hover');
}).on('mouseleave', function(e){
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
  $('.outer').addClass('hover');
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FjyLG/)

Comment: See comment on Agush's answer.

Comment: This is not really hackish, nor does it have the problem that Agush's does when you leave the inner div, but are still in the outer div.

Comment: Okay so it's not 'hackish' but it isn't as clean as I'd like. It's what I'm already doing as a work around.